# Why is ActualHeight set to NaN?

Tags: silverlight, actualheight

I am new to Silverlight and I just wanted to ask why my `ActualHeight` was set to NaN? It has a width and height of 500, but when compiled, it gives an error that says that `ActualHeight` is equal to NaN. Is there some other way to do this? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: In your question you wrote "height was set to NaN" - headline says ActualHeight is NaN - So what is exactly the problem? Normally you set the "Height" property in your productive code to some value - ActualHeight is a resized value depending on browser window size / parent container size

Comment: So ActualHeight doesn't work when height is defined?

Comment: Height of what? By the way, is this really a JavaScript question?

Comment: I am no wpf / xaml expert - But if i have to guess: Maybe ActualHeight is not set as long as no resize is required. Try to to force resizeing and see what happens, i am no expert :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NaN stands for "Not a Number".

1).When you have set the width of the object explicitly `ActualWidth` and `RenderSize.Width` will be set to 0.0. 
2). When you have set the width of the object to Auto Width will be set to NaN.

Comment: nice, thanks for the answer. It's quite bugging me not to know these things.